# Why SCSS compile error in atom?

Tags: sass, compiler-errors, atom-editor

I need help! I installed sass-autocompile in Atom. Created .scss file. But I have error when I want to compile it.

[image: Error in Atom]

Comment: You need to install node-sass globally: `npm install node-sass -g`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install node-sass globally. [npm node sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass)

Install:

```
$ npm install -g node-sass
```

Check in command line:

```
$ node-sass -v
```

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `node-sass` is not installed in your system, you need to install (globally, so any application or command line execution could reference it without the full path to the binary file) it by running the following command:

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

Read more about installing node packages globally [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally).

Hope it helps.